# Benefits of compiling with version 4.1 vs. version 2.3 of Android SDK?

Tags: android

If I'm not using anything which requires 4.1 of android, is there any good reason I should compile the app with the newest SDK and not compile it with an older one?

Would my app run faster if I compiled my application with the 4.1 SDK rather than with the 2.3 SDK, or would it be the same since I'm not using any of the new features introduced in ICS?

Answer (score 1):

You may be using new features "under the hood" like performance improvements. Since they are not always strictly backwards compatible make sure to test your app after you have increased the target version.

If you specify a lower target version the device will often fall back to the previous implementation in order not to break existing apps.